# select2 inside render method of a backbone view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, jquery-select2

I've a Backbone view which is expected to render a select input using [Select2](https://select2.github.io/).

```
Select2Cell = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: "select",

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.data = options.data;
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.select2({data: this.data});
        return this;
    }
});
```

I'm rendering this view inside the `render()` of another view:

```
CellsContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function() {
        var view = new Select2Cell({data: [{id: 1, text: "Item 1"}]});
        this.$el.append(view.render().$el);
        return this;
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I render `CellsContainerView`, it does not display select2.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var containerView = new CellsContainerView({el: "#container"});
    containerView.render();
});
```

Comment: Since you edited the typos, your code works out of the box. You'll need to provide an actual problem for us to help. Which versions of underscore, jquery, backbone, select2 are you using?

Answer (score 0):

*This answer was written before OP fixed the typos in his code.*

[Select2 data](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data) needs to be an array **of objects**. You're passing an invalid array, notice the missing brackets `{}`:

```
[id: 1, text: "Item 1"]
```

So the options passed to the select view should be changed to:

```
{ data: [{ id: 1, text: "Item 1" }]}
```

Here's a demo of your code with the fix:

```js
var Select2Cell = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: "select",

  initialize: function(options) {
    this.data = options.data;
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.select2({
      data: this.data
    }); // there was also a missing closing brace here
    return this;
  }
});

var CellsContainerView = Backbone.View.extend({
  render: function() {
    var view = new Select2Cell({
      data: [{
        id: 1,
        text: "Item 1"
      }]
    });
    this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    return this;
  }
});

var containerView = new CellsContainerView({
  el: "#container"
});
containerView.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: my bad id didn't put {} in the question, but in my code I am passing an array of objects to select2, its still not working

Comment: @MuhammadArsal look at my runnable snippet, it works, so use that as a reference to find what's not working in your code.